# Disable content-type detection for CSS types in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firewall, css, content-type-association

## Background

When connected to the corporate network, certain firewall rules are changing the content type of CSS files from `text/css` to `text/html`.

## Problem

Changing the media type for CSS files to HTML breaks certain sites, including superuser.com, stackoverflow.com, and the entire StackExchange network. The debugger shows:

> The stylesheet https://server/auD?origurl=https... was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.

Without CSS, those websites are unusable. Fixing the firewall is not an option (corporate won't relax the rule).

[image: stackexchange screenshot]

## Workarounds

- Disconnecting from the corporate network resolves the issue, but it's time consuming to connect/disconnect many times a day.
- Chromium on Linux works fine (i.e., it seems to ignore content-type/media type mismatches), but I have Firefox customizations that make this an unappealing option.
- Loading the sites in Firefox when not connected to the corporate network will add the files to the cache so that Firefox doesn't retrieve them when re-connected to the corporate network. This is a good temporary solution, but inevitably the cache expires, forcing another disconnect to refresh the cache.

## Question

How do you instruct Firefox to accept CSS files having an HTML content type?

Comment: I think you are asking how to *enable* sniffing. Sniffing is used to disregard the content-type header. One problem is that *not sniffing* is a security feature that prevents browsers from executing arbitrary code that may have purposely been tagged/named something else, e.g. a file named .png with proper mime content tag that is actually javascript might be executed if the browser sniffs it as an executable. I think they call this a confusion attack.

Comment: I've removed the reference to sniffing, Yorik, as it isn't really relevant to my question. Thanks for the additional info, I'm not overly concerned with Firefox's rationale, only how to make the sites work again while connected to the corporate network. Any ideas?

Comment: A) Is it possible to correct the "certain firewall rules are changing the content type of CSS files from text/css to text/html" part? B) It may be intentional on the part of whoever controls the rules to discourage access to some sites, however crudely they do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [simple-modify-headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/simple-modify-header/) add-on ([repo](https://github.com/didierfred/SimpleModifyHeaders)) has got you covered:

> The extension rewrites the headers based on a rules table.

Conveniently it also provides import and export of rules. Change the Content-Type of CSS files to `text/css` as follows:

1. Create a new file named `fix-css.conf` (must have `.conf` extension) having the following contents:

   ```json
   {
     "format_version": "1.2",
     "target_page": "*://*/*css*",
     "headers": [
       {
         "url_contains": "",
         "action": "modify",
         "header_name": "Content-Type",
         "header_value": "text/css",
         "comment": "fix css",
         "apply_on": "res",
         "status": "on"
       }
     ],
     "debug_mode": false,
     "show_comments": true,
     "use_url_contains": false
   }
   ```
2. Open the add-on user interface via *Simple Modify Headers* <kbd>[image]</kbd> toolbar button  > *Configure*
3. Click the  <kbd>⇲ Import</kbd> button.
4. Select the `.conf` file in the file dialog.
5. Confirm the *This will erase your actual configuration* warning
6. Click the <kbd>START</kbd> button at the top right to enable the modification.

[image: simple-modify-headers configuration to fix CSS]

---

Re: Internal Firefox setting

There's no setting in about:config, the CSS Content-Type [must be](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/6755226f52a02eac8b18f25a6f522e9c0814b628/layout/style/Loader.cpp#734-760) text/css, unknown or empty (or in quirks mode the file come from the same origin):

> In standards mode, a style sheet must have one of these MIME types to be processed at all. In quirks mode, we accept any MIME type, but only if the style sheet is same-origin with the requesting document or parent sheet. See [bug 524223](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=524223).

Comment: @harrymc In HTTP headers are present on request *and* response. `"apply_on": "res"` indicates that this rule applies to the response, which is exactly what the browser and the user are looking for.

Comment: It's _almost_ working. There may be an issue with the plugin. The following URL matches the regex, but the content-type isn't changed: `The stylesheet https://gateway.x.net/auD?origurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn%2esstatic%2enet%2fSites%2ftex%2fprimary%2ecss%3fv%3d3e640f30db89&wexps=1&_ordtok=jLk3WVRDKVhMM52nf3lQ36NJ5R was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.`

Comment: I changed the expression to `*://*/*static*css*` because there were some false hits. All the CSS looks to be loading. There are now JavaScript and cookie problems that are revealed. Ironically, they've also blocked `i.stack.imgur.com` recently. I'll accept your answer because it _should_ work in theory, despite not solving the problem for me. Note that the add-on doesn't seem to allow assigning different expressions to different rules, so I can't distinguish rules for JavaScript, which is also being set to `text/html` inappropriately by the gateway rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a bookmarklet to inline a page's referenced CSS files as `<style>` tags into the document. This requires one click per page load but no additional software.

###### Prerequisite: Ensure the *Bookmarks Toolbar* is shown

1. Right-click on some free space besides the URL bar
2. Hover over *Bookmarks Toolbar*
3. Click *Always Show* if not checked already. The toolbar will appear below the URL bar.

###### Create the bookmarklet

1. Right-click on the *Bookmarks Toolbar*
2. Click on *Add Bookmark...*
3. Enter a name like *Inline CSS* into the *Name* field
4. Paste the following into the *URL* field:

   ```js
   javascript: (async function () {
     function appendCSS(css) {
       const style = document.createElement("style");
       style.innerText = css;
       document.head.appendChild(style);
     }

     for(const link of document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"][href]')){
       appendCSS(await (await fetch(link.href)).text());
     }
   })();
   ```
5. Click on the newly created *bookmarklet* (a bookmark containing JavaScript code that will be executed on click)

The page should immediately look better. Note it has no error handling, so if nothing changes open the Developer Tools to see potential errors.

Comment: That is a nice improvement, thank you. The page remains functionally broken and mostly unreadable, though. Probably for other gateway- or firewall-related reasons than the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If the MIME type is specified via `Content-Type` embedded
in the HTML, you may change it by using
Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey.

But if it is reported by the server when the browser does the
GET of the CSS file, then you must intercept the answer
to the GET request and modify it before it gets to the browser.
This would require a proxy between the browser and the internet
that can be programmed for doing this.

A fast research found
[requestly.io](https://requestly.io/)
whose free plan might be enough for such modifications,
or another of its
[alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/requestly/),
such as the free
[Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: It's reported by the server when going through the corporate gateway. Ideally, I'd be looking for an `about:config` option to disable the behaviour.